# Chef - puts message in end of chef-client run?

Tags: chef-infra, puts

Is it possible to print out a message in the end of a chef-client run? Something like:

```
######################

Attention: blablabla

######################
Chef Client finished, 19/222 resources updated in 18 seconds
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can laverage [event handlers](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#event-handlers), and it would look something like:

```rb
Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_completed do
    puts "Attention: blablabla"
  end
end
```